# Speed up the SQL request

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I would like to know which request (and which index) will be the best to do that. I Use Symfony. But for this request I used normal SQL.
I did tables with doctrine.

I would like to have the asset of each Client.

Tables:

```
Client ~ 20 000 rows ->  Index : foreign key,id, reference, (reference, id), 
Invoice ~ 690 000 rows -> Index : foreign key,id, reference,(client_id, id), 
Invoice_line ~ 4 000 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, qty, price, reference,(invoice_id, quantity, unit_price) ,
credit_note ~ 40 000 rows -> Index : foreign key,id, reference, 
credit_note_line ~ 61 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, id, qty, price, reference, 
Product ~ 75 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, id, reference,
```

the line represent one product with is price and quantity

Asset for one Client = Total Client's Invoices - Total  Client's Credit Notes

each invoice (and credit note) have 1 or X invoice_lines which represent one product with quantities and price.

ex:
[image: invoice_line]

So I did this request:

```
SELECT
    a1.reference,
    a1.id,
    SUM(a1.balance) AS "asset"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c2.reference,
        c2.id,
        SUM(il.quantity * il.unit_price) AS "balance"
    FROM CLIENT AS
        c2
    INNER JOIN invoice AS i
    ON
        i.client_id = c2.id
    INNER JOIN invoice_line AS il
    ON
        i.id = il.invoice_id
GROUP BY
    c2.reference
UNION ALL
SELECT
    c1.reference,
    c1.id,
    - SUM(cnl.quantity * cnl.unit_price) AS "balance"
FROM CLIENT AS
    c1
INNER JOIN credit_note AS cn
ON
    cn.client_id = c1.id
INNER JOIN credit_note_line AS cnl
ON
    cn.id = cnl.credit_note_id
GROUP BY
    c1.reference
) AS a1
GROUP BY
    reference
ORDER BY
    `asset`
DESC
```

It give me the right answer but it's very long (15s). How can I reduce the request time (like 2s)?

I would like also the asset for N-1 so I have to do twice this request and it take too much time.

Comment: I don't understand your table descriptions. What does `Client ~ 20 000 rows ->  Index : foreign key,id, reference, (reference, id)` mean? The client table has about 20k rows, okay. And there is a foreign key index? On which column, to which table? Do I read this correctly that there are three indexes on the table? Index #1 on `id`. Index #2 on `reference`. Index #3 on `reference, id`? And the `id` uniquely identifies a row in the table? And the `reference` uniquely identifies a row in the table? So there are two different IDs to identify a client? Yes? If so, why? If not, what is `reference`?

Comment: The query gets you all balances for all clients. Is this what you want? What does "I would like also the asset for N-1" mean? What is "N-1"?

Comment: Oops, just saw this is a year old. It only got pushed up because of an edit yesterday. Sorry.